# What does following kind of url mean ? Is it a some another page in php?

Tags: php, facebook, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [username urls like twitter and facebook](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3129939/username-urls-like-twitter-and-facebook)
>   [How to get user friendly URLs without any file extensions?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14211303/how-to-get-user-friendly-urls-without-any-file-extensions)

Something like `https://www.facebook.com/n26n`
 is the url when you view somebody's profile.
How can you have a url without a file extension? 
As facebook uses PHP, could this be done by php?

Sorry, i am just a starter so I am just curious  about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in a number of ways, the most common using an apache mod called [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is just an internal redirect. Facebook knows to that those types of URLs are used to point to user profiles. The `n26n` portion is probably the `base32` encoding of the user's ID that you are accessing.

Comment: actually, that n26n portion is not any encoded string, it´s the vanity url. the one you are able to set by yourself as user.